# what is equivalent of prestodb date_trunc in hive

Tags: hive, presto

I have a prestodb query which uses DATE_TRUNC like this:

```
DATE_TRUNC('week', DATE(dd.signup_timestamp))
```

what will be its equivalent in hive?

Another similar question is, what is equivalent of this expression in presto in hive:

```
date_sub(date_trunc('week', now()), 180)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select date_sub('2018-09-05', cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(), 'u') AS int)) as c;
output: 2018-09-03
```

And for other:

```
date_sub(date_sub(from_unixtimestamp(unix_timestamp(), cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(), 'u'), 'u')as int)), 180)
```